# React New Massages in One Channel

Tags: discord.js

How to React New Messages in One Channel?

Discord.js

I tried:

```js
if (client.channels.get('652238008287756291')) {
    message.react(':apple:');
    message.react(':tangerine:');
    message.react(':grapes:');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`client.channels.get('ID')` will not work. This will be an Object / undefined depending if the channel exists or not. The `Message` has a property called `channel`, which is the `TextChannel` in which the message was sent.

Then you can check if the channel's ID equals to `652238008287756291`.

---

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.channel.id == "652238008287756291") {
        message.react(":apple:")
        message.react(":tangerine:")
        message.react(":grapes:")
    }
});
```